# What is the need to have the Unicode class?

Tags: 8

Why is it necessary to have the [`Unicode`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Unicode.php/class/Unicode/8.2.x) class?

What does [`Unicode::strtoupper()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Unicode.php/function/Unicode%3A%3Astrtoupper/8.2.x) or [`Unicode::strtolower()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Unicode.php/function/Unicode%3A%3Astrtolower/8.2.x) do that cannot be done just using native the PHP functions [`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) or [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)?

Comment: I am going to guess that using Unicode provides a common implementation everyone can use that solves or handles typical/common problems from using the php function on their own implementations. Note that in previous versions we had drupal_strtolower. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!unicode.inc/function/drupal_strtolower/7.x

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reasons to have its own replacement of `strtoupper` and `strtolower()` is to support multi-bytes string in those sites where the [Multibyte String](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension is installed, and in those sites where that extension is not installed.

`strtoupper()` and `strtolower()` don't support multi-byte strings. Even in the case Drupal would not try to use the *Multibyte String* extension when installed, `Unicode::strtoupper()` and `Unicode::strtolower()` would not be reduced to simply calls to `strtoupper()` and `strtolower()`. Their code would probably be the following one.

```
public static function strtoupper($text) {
  // Use C-locale for ASCII-only uppercase.
  $text = strtoupper($text);
  // Case flip Latin-1 accented letters.
  $text = preg_replace_callback('/\xC3[\xA0-\xB6\xB8-\xBE]/', '\Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode::caseFlip', $text);
  return $text;
}
```

```
public static function strtolower($text) {
  // Use C-locale for ASCII-only lowercase.
  $text = strtolower($text);
  // Case flip Latin-1 accented letters.
  $text = preg_replace_callback('/\xC3[\x80-\x96\x98-\x9E]/', '\Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode::caseFlip', $text);
  return $text;
}
```

If Drupal required the *Multibyte String* extension to be present, then `Unicode::strtoupper()` and `Unicode::strtolower()` would not be necessary, since Drupal would use directly `mb_strtoupper()` and `mb_strtolower()`.

That is not different from what happened in previous versions, except they implemented [`drupal_strtouppper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) [and drupal_strtolower()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21unicode.inc/function/drupal_strtolower/7.x). If you look at the code, it is not much different.

```
function drupal_strtoupper($text) {
  global $multibyte;
  if ($multibyte == UNICODE_MULTIBYTE) {
    return mb_strtoupper($text);
  }
  else {
    // Use C-locale for ASCII-only uppercase
    $text = strtoupper($text);
    // Case flip Latin-1 accented letters
    $text = preg_replace_callback('/\xC3[\xA0-\xB6\xB8-\xBE]/', '_unicode_caseflip', $text);
    return $text;
  }
}
```

```
public static function strtoupper($text) {
  if (static::getStatus() == static::STATUS_MULTIBYTE) {
    return mb_strtoupper($text);
  }
  else {
    // Use C-locale for ASCII-only uppercase.
    $text = strtoupper($text);
    // Case flip Latin-1 accented letters.
    $text = preg_replace_callback('/\xC3[\xA0-\xB6\xB8-\xBE]/', '\Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode::caseFlip', $text);
    return $text;
  }
}
```

Comment: Concise yet thorough.